# export pdf using angular ignie UI for angular

Tags: angular, typescript, infragistics, igx-grid

I'm using angular typescript 12 , and i have integrated angular ignite UI grid
i need to export my grid into pdf , however, i didn't find how to export the pdf using Igx-Grid.

does Igx-Grid currently provide PDF exporter? or if there is any way that can help me make that i would like to know please .

here is the grid that i have used :

```
<igx-grid #grid id="grid" [data]="liste" [allowFiltering]="true"  [autoGenerate]="true">
</igx-grid>
```

Answer (score 2):

for the time being working on PDF exporting feature is not part of the Roadmap, although [there is an issue](https://github.com/IgniteUI/igniteui-angular/issues/5696) part of the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/IgniteUI/igniteui-angular) where you can place your comment and help with prioritizing it.

In order to receive a notification whenever new information is available on the   Feature Request, make sure that you are subscribed to the issue. This can be achieved via the “Subscribe” button.